# Machine is not on the network when trying to connect MQTT?

Tags: android, mqtt, android-wifi, paho, wifip2p

Hi developers in my app i perform two operation one is to connect a specific **wifi** by providing **SSID and password** programmatically and another one is interact with **MQTT**. Both operation work fine individually , but when first connect to **WIFI programmatically** and after that if i am trying to connect **MQTT** it throws **Exception**.

```
MqttException (0) - java.net.SocketException: socket failed: ENONET (Machine is not on the network)
1608792187.259 31589-31589/com.asiczen.azlock W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:38)
1608792187.259 31589-31589/com.asiczen.azlock W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:690)
1608792187.259 31589-31589/com.asiczen.azlock W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

And here is my Wifi connection.

```
private void connectToBrideAboveQ(String networkSSID, String networkPass){
        WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder builder = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder();
        builder.setSsid(networkSSID);
        builder.setWpa2Passphrase(networkPass);

        WifiNetworkSpecifier wifiNetworkSpecifier = builder.build();

        NetworkRequest.Builder networkRequestBuilder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
        networkRequestBuilder.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
        networkRequestBuilder.removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET);
        networkRequestBuilder.setNetworkSpecifier(wifiNetworkSpecifier);

        NetworkRequest networkRequest = networkRequestBuilder.build();
        cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        networkCallback = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback(){
            @Override
            public void onAvailable(@NonNull Network network) {
                super.onAvailable(network);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d(TAG, "onAvailable: "+network);
                cm.bindProcessToNetwork(network);
            }
        };
        cm.requestNetwork(networkRequest, networkCallback);

    }
```

And here is mqtt connection code

```
mqttConnectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
mqttConnectOptions.setCleanSession(true);
mqttClient = new MqttAndroidClient(this, url, id);
        mqttClient.setCallback(new MqttCallback() {
            @Override
            public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {
                doConnectTask = true;
                Log.d(TAG, "MQTT connectionLost: ");
            }

            @Override
            public void messageArrived(String s, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {

            }

            @Override
            public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {

            }
        });

mqttClient.connect(mqttConnectOptions, null, new IMqttActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(IMqttToken iMqttToken) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "MQTT CONNECTED: ");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(IMqttToken iMqttToken, Throwable throwable) {
                        doConnectTask = true;
                        //setNewMqttClient();
                        throwable.printStackTrace();
                        Log.d(TAG, "MQTT FAILER onFailure: ");
                    }
                });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the question here? I can't see in the code where you are using the callback provided by `ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback()`  to wait to trigger the MQTT connection.

Comment: Why are you posting from 2 accounts?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solve this before connecting to MQTT just call **cm.bindProcessToNetwork(null);** this solve my problem.